# How to monkey patch a function using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I am trying to test a function that reads in a csv file with some numbers and calculates the area. I am trying to test it by patching a pandas function using pytest, specifically read_csv function such that it returns the same dataframe every time. For some reason I can't seem to monkeypatch it

**circle.py**

```
import math
import pandas as pd
def get_area(r):
    if not type(r) in [int, float]:
        raise TypeError("Non numeric value") 
    return math.pi*(r**2)
def read_rads():
    df = pd.read_csv('radii.csv', header=None, index_col=None)
    return( [get_area(x[0]) for x in df.iterrows()])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_area(2))
    print(read_rads())
```

**test_circle.py**

```
import pytest
import circle
import math
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import pandas as pd
def test_get_area():
    assert circle.get_area(1) == math.pi * 1**2
    assert circle.get_area(3) == math.pi * 3**2
def test_if_get_area_for_string_input():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        circle.get_area('some string')
def test_read_radii(monkeypatch):
    # We have to mock the response of pd.read_csv
    def mock_read_csv(*args, **kwargs):
        return pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,5])

    # apply the monkeypatch for requests.get to mock_get
    monkeypatch.setattr(pd, "read_csv", mock_read_csv)
    res = circle.read_rads()
    assert res == [0.0, 3.141592653589793, 12.566370614359172, 28.274333882308138, 78.53981633974483]
```

radii is just a csv file with a number on each line, nothing special.

I tried following along with https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-returned-objects-building-mock-classes
I understand that they used a class for the test, but why isn't the read_csv function being monkeypatched? And is this the right way to patch in the data for use in the function?

Comment: What's the result of assert statement?

Comment: I had radii.csv be a file with 1 2 3 4 in it, it should give us the same as the mock csv but be [0,1,2,3,4] so the area for those numbers. Like its still reading in the csv file

Comment: You're accessing dataframe's row index instead of row value. That's why it's always returning [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. Try different sequence of mocked Datafrrame to see it e.g.`[1, 2, 3]`. You can fix it by using column name or use `df.itertuples()` to iterate.